Is machine learning model deployment part of data science?
I applied for a (Supposedly) data scientist role. I'm surprised that part of my job scope involves deployment machine learning models to production/cloud. I would have thought isn't that the role of a data engineer? A data scientist role is to analyse datasets, coming out with insights and to research on machine learning algorithms. I'm surprised that they also expected me to know how to deploy models on cloud as a data scientist. Is deploying models part of the usual job scope for a data scientist? Or did the company mix up the roles between a data scientist and a data engineer?
